# How to extract Bluetooth Scan Results from intent?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

How would someone extract Scan Results from an intent object in C#?

I am having a callback class that derives from BroadcastReceiver. In the same class I have this override method that I am getting scanned bluetooth devices.

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice)
}
```

I need to know if there is way to extract ScanResults from that intent object so I can convert those ScanResults to byte[] and start parsing the information.

```
public override void OnScanResult(ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
{
}
```

In other words, can I achieve the results from the second method in regards of ScanResult using the first one described?

Comment: Not sure about your situation, but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/39652108/199364 help?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) , it can serialize `any object` into json string and then deserialize back.

And here we need to convert `ScanResult` to `string` first and then pass it  into `Intent` and then deserialize the json to `ScanResult` in BroadcastReceiver receiver class .

1. Install the plugin : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ .
2. Convert `ScanResult` to Json string .

   ```cs
   public override void OnScanResult(ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
   {
      string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
      Intent intent = new Intent("MyAction");
      intent.PutExtra("MyJson",json);
      SendBroadcast(intent);
   }
   ```
3. Convert Json string to `ScanResult`.

   ```cs
   public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
      if ("MyAction".Equals(intent.Action))
      {
          string json = intent.GetStringExtra("MyJson");
          ScanResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScanResult>(json);
          // do something
      }
   }
   ```